# how to add an UISwitch to a cell in a grouped table view

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitableview

I am trying to add a UISwitch to a cell in a grouped table view but I am not getting the proper way to do this. Please help me.
Thanks & Regards,
Chakri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `UISwitch` button as accessory for `UITableViewCell`:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellId = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell* cellView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if(!cellView) {
        cellView = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        UISwitch* switchBtn = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        [switchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onSwitchBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cellView.accessoryView = switchBtn;
    }
    return cellView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate to C# the existing (Objective-C) answers but, since you're using MonoTouch, you should have a look at [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) (and it's sample application).

It provides a much easier API on top of `UITableView` and still covers most of the common usage/scenario requiring tables.

See the screenshots (from previous link) to see `UISwitch` being used in cells.

Answer (score 0):

are you using storyboards or xibs?
I think in storyboard you can drag the UISwith to the cell.

If you are using xibs, you will need a custom cell. Using interface builder drag a UITableViewCell to your xib outside the tableview, drag the UISwitch inside the UITableViewCell, and put a IBOutlet in the UITableViewCell, then

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == rowWhereYouWantTheCellWithTheUISwitch){
    return UITableViewCellWithTheSwitchName;
}
}
```

rowWhereYouWantTheCellWithTheUISwitch is the number of the cell where you want your custom cell.
UITableViewCellWithTheSwitchName is the name of the IBOutlet you created.